# JQ Select items that do not match string

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli, jq

I've got a group of AWS instances that I'm parsing via aws ec describe-instances. I'm looking to trim out all the records whose IP's do not start with '10.10'.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --no-paginate --filter "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].{Private:PrivateIpAddress,PublicDNS:PublicDnsName,PublicIP:PublicIpAddress}' | jq '.[] | select( .Private | contains("10.10"))'
```

This gets me the exact opposite of what I want. It seems logical that I should be able to negate the contains in some way - but I've not been able to glean it from the documentation, nor through experimentation. My jq proficiency is middling, so perhaps I'm using the wrong operator or function here.

While i WOULD like an answer to this specific jq question - I'll accept an answer that utilizes JMESPath through the --query switch yield the same result.

Comment: Just add a `not` to the end of the select predicate.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what the syntax should be. Could you elaborate? I've tried adding "not" in a few different places but I keep getting jq compile errors.

Comment: `select(.Private | contains("10.10") | not)` You probably should use [`startswith/1`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#startswith(str)) as well since you specifically don't want that in the beginning of the string.

Comment: D'OH! It never occurred to me that the not should come after the contains.... that did it. Thanks!. If you want to formulate your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Jeff Marcado's answer in the comments will be accepted if he writes it up as a full fledged answer. In the meantime, since I had hit a wall with trying to get JQ to do it, I experimented with the --query syntax for AWS to get this.

It might be a bit better, since this catches only objects that start with 10.10, whereas the jq from above will catch any object that contains 10.10, so things like 10.100. or 110.100, etc... will get through. That's assuming there is not a similar operator to "starts_with" in jq. Probably there is. Regardless, I'm putting this here because it worked for my end goal and may be helpful to someone else at some point.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
    --no-paginate --filter "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" \
    --query 'Reservations[].Instances[?starts_with(PrivateIpAddress, `10.10.`) == `false`]' |
  jq '.[] | .[] | {PrivateIpAddress, PublicIpAddress, PublicDnsName}'
```

Comment: Seems that Jeff's answer above actually states that "startswith" DOES exist . So there's that. Thanks again @Jeff Mercado